# UIApplication openURL with tel link does nothing, but returns true

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8

As of iOS8 `UIApplication canOpenURL` returns true on my iPad, for `tel:` URLs.  I wouldn't mind that, since technically an iPad can make a phone call, however...

When I call `UIApplication openURL`... nothing happens.  The function returns true, no error.  So I have a bad UX because there is a button that "does nothing" in my app now, and I have no way to know it "did nothing".

How are others handling this?

Comment: I ran into this when iOS 8 was in beta last year. Never got a good answer why this happens (posted on the Apple dev forums). Some people guessed it had to do with call handoffs.